# Advice on execution of SQL Job Agents from Code Behind across multiple servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, sql-agent-job

So I have a job that runs on 7 different DB's on 7 different servers across the country. The job is not a scheduled job as we can't predict when it will need to be ran each month or every other month, or on what date of which month etc. In the past the client VPN to each server, then logs on to each database and then starts the job manually. Each job has 7 steps with each step exporting a large sum of data to an excel file for later import into a proprietary piece of software that only accepts excel data. kinda sucks but this is how it's always been done. I can't change any of the steps after the job is started but I can help make things easier by removing some of the initial stress of 7 different VPN connections with 7 more server login's etc.

I have created a simple web app in C#/.Net that allows the user to select which server, then hit the start button and this would then somehow start the sql job from the code behind. Since I can place this app on the central server It would not require individual VPN logon's or DB logins. All the user would have to do is login to the web app to fire everything. I have found references that I tried that had me firing off code that would log onto the server and start the job via direct access from C#. However between all the permission issues and other errors I feel this is a horrible direction to go. I found some references that said I could execute some stored proc that would fire the jobs on each server and this seems to be the direction to go as far as simple go.

I am looking for advice on the best way to go about accomplishing this task. Can I just write a proc and then drop that on each server and then depending on the server selected in the dropdown list on the web app it will then fire the proc on that server to start the job? That seems easy enough and would be more than capable of doing with little permissions issues.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is SQL server, the syntax you are looking for is:

> EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_start_job] 'Name of the job to start'

As long as you have execute permissions on the stored procedure, you don't need anything else.
You can run this from your .net code or you can create linked servers and have a procedure fire this for every server. The code changes slightly in this case to include the linked server name:

> EXEC [linked server name].[msdb].[dbo].[sp_start_job] 'Name of the job to start'